# Anything preventing modern GCC from running on vintage processor?

Tags: c, gcc

First the background, I have a Siemens PC-MX2 vintage "minicomputer" that runs a time-sharing Unix OS called Sinix for up to 12 users. It has the NS32016 processor which was the first 32bit microprocessor if I'm not mistaken. Along with MMU, FPU, timer chip, and interrupt control unit. So, everything needed to run a modern OS like early versions of Linux (not including a ton of work porting software).

While I have the dream to get Linux running on it, at least the bare essentials after cutting and slashing away at the OS. I only have 4MB of memory at the moment. My C skills are intermediate at the moment, so who knows if it will ever happen. But at least it gives me a cool system to tinker on until I'm an old man :-)

As part of this dream that I have started to learn to program C on this system. It's inconvenient and infuriating at times. It uses a C compiler that was created before the first version of ANSI C, and after K&R C. Documentation is scarce.

So, is there anything physically in the system keeping me from adding the NS32k back into GCC and getting a compiler for C11? Does C11 require so much memory that I shouldn't even try?

Comment: you are probably better off cross compiling, run the compiler on a modern linux but tell it to generate code for the processor. Thats a non trivial thing but is probably easier than getting the whole compiler ported over. In this case maybe clang/llvm is better choice

Comment: http://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/TutorialLLVMBackendCpu0.pdf

Comment: I predict that the 4MB RAM would be a hard barrier to overcome for running a modern compiler natively on that hardware.  You didn't say how much persistent storage you have, but that could very well be an issue, too.  And GCC has a relatively close relationship with Glibc.  You can probably substitute [uClibc](https://uclibc-ng.org/), at least at runtime, but it may be harder to work with the system's original C library.

Comment: And once you have a working strategy for C compilation and library, you might find [busybox](https://busybox.net/about.html) useful for providing implementations of many of the standard utilities.

Comment: It has a 72MB hard drive, thanks for the replies.

Comment: @pm100 When cross compiling is the *easy* solution, this just might apply, "When the going gets tough, find something easier."  ;-)

Comment: A good start would be to just install an old version of gcc that supported the target (3.x?), since those versions were a lot lighter on memory. That will at least get you C99, and that's probably pretty good.  The main addition in C11 was multithreading and the memory model, but I assume (?) this machine only has one CPU, so you aren't likely to be doing much of that anyway.

Comment: You might be interested in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com, which is perhaps a better place for questions like this.

Comment: From the wikipedia page, there are a number of links. One is: http://cpu-ns32k.net/Gnutool.html